# Is there a way to mimic the effect of the time.sleep() function without pausing the entire program?

Tags: python, python-3.x, time, while-loop

I am a new python 3.9 user who's trying to step up my coding. I'm writing a program that uses a while loop and will call functions to press keys based on user input. My code basically looks like:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
from graphics import *
import time
    
def wack():
   M = Controller()
   for i in range(3):
      M.press('a')
      time.sleep(1)    # This guy right here is the issue
      M.release('a')

def main():
    click = Win.checkMouse()
    while not click(click, exit_box):
       click = Win.checkMouse()
       if *input* == *correct string*:
          wack()
```

I have a graphics window with an exit button and when exit is clicked, it terminates the program and closes the window. The issue is that the `time.sleep(1)` doesn't pause the inputs or that point in the code, it pauses the entire program suspending the while loop which is not what I want it to do.

Searching about the time function hasn't provided any clear solutions since `time.sleep()` seems to be the most popular pausing function in python.

Comment: I read through this a few times, but it is a bit vague. When you say 'graphics window' do you mean video game, like are you trying to make a bot? Also, for time.sleep, all that does is pause in the program, so within the for loop inside the wack function, all sleep will ever do is pause on that line, that is all time.sleep does. It sleeps at that line of code for a predetermined amount of time and then starts up again, if you are not trying to do that, it is not the correct thing to use. So what are you trying to achieve from start to finish on this one might be more help.

Comment: @NewCoder18  From start to finish, this code accepts a user input in the form of pre-set codes. The code then activates and inputs button presses continuously. The whole point of this is to be a trainer that I can use on an emulated Pokemon game. So the user clicks on a graphics window created by the program, enters their code, and can still interact with the window while the code works in the background.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`asyncio` is an amazing feature added in `python3.7` which allows you to wait for an object or function(callled a `coroutine` in the context of asynchronous python) to get a result while the rest of the program executes.

`asyncio` has  a sleep method which paused only the asynchronous function(`coroutine`) and lets the rest of the code in the program execute

**This is how:**

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
from graphics import *
import time
import asyncio

#This is the asnychronous funtion    
async def wack():
   M = Controller()
   for i in range(3):
      M.press('a')
      await asyncio.sleep(1)#this sleeps the function but allows the rest of the program to work
      M.release('a')

def main():
    click = Win.checkMouse()
    while not click(click, exit_box):
       click = Win.checkMouse()
       if *input* == *correct string*:
          asyncio.run(wack()) #calling the asynchronous funtion
```

Here is a tutorial on understanding [asyn io](https://realpython.com/async-io-python/) for python